# How do I know how much time is remaining until I can use Alchemy API again?

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

Trying to use Alchemy API and getting the message

```
 Oct 07, 2015 8:48:44 PM com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.AlchemyService execute
 SEVERE: {"error":"daily-transaction-limit-exceeded","code":429}
```

Obviously, I have to wait 24h to use it again.

The problem is: is there a way to check when exactly the API will be available again?

UPDATE: it's been more than 24h and I still get this message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the service is marked as down. The way to ask for the status or a possible ETA for this service is to send a request to Bluemix Support either through "Go to Bluemix Support" in Bluemix dashboard or by sending a mail to support@bluemix.net.

Comment: Status information about Bluemix services is publicly posted here: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status    Please check that page and open a ticket if an issue is not listed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error format, I guess you are using the [java-SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-wrapper). It will give you the number of transactions as part of the response, please make sure your call doesn't have more than 10.000 transactions. Combined and DataNews calls usually use thousand of transactions.

In order to get the number of transactions you can use:

```
AlchemyDataNews service = new AlchemyDataNews();
service.setApiKey("<api_key>");

VolumeResult result = service.getVolume("now-7d", "now", "12h");
System.out.println("Transactions: #" + result.getTotalTransactions())
System.out.println(result);
```

See more examples [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-wrapper/tree/master/examples/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud).